# Does a call stack grow first in / first out in C++?

Tags: c++, callstack

> Each time we call the function, the stack of activation records (usually just called the stack) grows with one record. Conversely, when the function returns, its record is no longer used and so on. The stack (also called the call stack) is a data structure that grows and shrinks at one end according to the rule **first in and first out**.

Is the last line correct? I read it in the book programming principles and practices using C++, by Bjarne Stroustrup.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by _"the statement is like"_?  This is not a properly formed sentence.

Comment: Why are you questioning the last line? I don't mean that you should simply accept what you read, but it seems strange to randomly pick and choose some lines to believe and some to distrust. What led you to pick this line in particular? Is there something specific that does not make sense?

Comment: I've found a copy of the text online: you have indeed quoted correctly from the second-last paragraph of section 8.5.  Nothing related in the [errata, here](https://www.stroustrup.com/PPPslides/PPP2errata.html).  Beats me, but definitely a stack is (first in, last out) and (last in, first out).  It is decidedly not (first in first out).  Stroustrup himself says that in his glossary [here](https://www.stroustrup.com/glossary.html#Gstack)  _"`stack` - (1) memory used to hold local variables for a function. (2) standard library *first-in-last-out* sequence. TC++PL 10.4.3, 17.3.1, D&E 2.3, 3.9."_

Comment: first in first out would mean that the first function you call (usually main in c++) gets cleaned up first. This is logically wrong. the main function is the LAST function that gets cleaned up after all other functions returned. 
I assume the book has a typo.

Comment: The emphasis added by Ataxias helps, but I still think a statement as to why you are questioning the last line would improve your question's presentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me show you how a call stack works: imagine you have a program, which contains some functions and subfunctions, like `f1()`, `f1.1()`, `f1.2()`, `f1.1.1()`, `f1.2.1()` and `f1.2.2()`, and you have following pieces of code:

```
int f1(){
  if (<condition>){ // B1
    return f1.1();
    } else {
    return f1.2();
  }
}

int f1.1(){
  int temp = -1; // B2
  return f1.1.1();
}

int f1.2(){
  if <other_condition>{
    return f1.2.1(); // B3
  } else {
    return f1.2.2();
  }
}

int f1.1.1(){
  int temp = 1001001;
  return temp;
}

int f1.2.1(){
  int temp = 1002001;
  return temp;
}

int f1.2.2(){
  int temp = 1002002; // B4
  return temp;
}
```

The B1-B4 mean that you put a breakpoint on that line, and the execution is done in such a way, that those breakpoints get hit. Let's see how the callstack look at those moments:

B1: Callstack:

```
f1()
```

B2 : Callstack:

```
f1.1()
f1()
```

B3 : Callstack:

```
f1.2() // at the moment of the breakpoint, f1.2.1() not yet executed.
f1()
```

B4 : Callstack:

```
f1.2.2()
f1.2()
f1()
```

The callstack gets filled from bottom to top: first `f1()` gets added (this function is being executed), when a subfunction (`f1.1()` or `f1.2()`) get executed, that one is added in top of the callstack. Once the execution is finished, it gets removed.

Answer (score 3):

It is a mistake. A stack is, **by definition**, last in first out (LIFO). A first in first out (FIFO) data structure would be a queue, not a stack.